# How to fix dent in B+W circular polarizing filter?

Tags: filters, repair, biermann-weber

I own a 77mm B+W Nano Kaesemann Circular Polarizer with Multi-Resistant Coating.  It has a small dent in the rim that makes turning it difficult.  Can this be repaired, and if so, where?  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but despite the cost, the best option may be to replace it.  Screwing a filter with a damaged thread onto your lens has the potential to damage the lens' thread too either by grinding it or warping it, plus even if you manage to fix it, it may never be as smooth as it originally was.  I'm guessing your lens is a fairly good one.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options basically, you can try to repair it yourself or you can go to any camera shop that performs general repairs.

If you try to do it yourself I would recommend a tool such as [this Camera Lens Vise Tool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J5F72AC).

Keep in mind that CPLs are multiple pieces of glass and quite fragile. With proper it can likely be repaired, but there is a chance of making it worse of course.